# Run development or production builds in Heroku according to NODE_ENV

Tags: node.js, express, heroku, npm, environment-variables

I have a react + express project where I do server side rendering. My folder structure is like this

```
root
 client
   build
   node_modules
   public
   src
   package.json
 node_modules
 routes
 server.js
 package.json
```

I have two Heroku dynos app-dev and app-prod and I use app-dev for development and app-prod for production and their environments have been set to dev and prod accordingly. My package.json looks like this

```json
{
  "name": "name",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node server",
    "server": "nodemon server",
    "client": "npm start --prefix client",
    "build": "cd client/ && npm install && npm run build",
    "dev": "concurrently \"npm run server\" \"npm run client\""
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "^1.18.3",
    "chalk": "^4.1.1",
    "concurrently": "^6.1.0",
    "connect-mongo": "^3.2.0",
    "cookie-parser": "^1.4.3",
    "cookie-session": "^2.0.0-beta.3",
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "dotenv": "^10.0.0",
    "express": "^4.16.4",
    "express-session": "^1.15.6",
    "express-validator": "^6.11.1",
    "mongoose": "^5.4.1",
    "mongoose-findorcreate": "^3.0.0",
    "morgan": "^1.10.0",
    "passport": "^0.4.0",
    "passport-google-oauth": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-google-oauth20": "^2.0.0",
    "passport-twitter": "^1.0.4",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

Now I have got a constants file in my client/src folder that had these

```
// Constants.js
const prod = {
     url: {
        SS_API_URL: 'https://prod.example.com',
     },
     keys:{
        SS_CLIENT_ID: 'prodClientId',
        SS_X_API_KEY: 'prodApiKey',
     }
};

const dev = {
     url: {
        SS_API_URL: 'https://dev.example.com',  
     },
     keys:{
        SS_CLIENT_ID: 'devClientId',
        SS_X_API_KEY: 'devApiKey',
     } 
};

export const config = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development' ? dev : prod;
```

Now when I upload to Heroku (app-dev) and it builds it, after that it seems to be using the prod.example.com instead of dev.example.com API endpoint. Since the NODE_ENV is development I thought it would take the SS_API_URL for dev but it is taking the SS_API_URL for prod

Answer (score 0):

You can add this variable on settings menu, "Config Vars", inside your heroku project. So you add NODE_ENV and value "production".

Comment: I have already added it using this command heroku config:set NODE_ENV=development and when I check it using heroku run node --app nameofapp
console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV) it shows two values - development and undefined